# Use a WPF Window in two ways

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a WPF Window with four buttons namely "Yes", "No", "Yes To All" and "No to All". In some cases I would need only "Yes" and "No" buttons. One way is to hide the other two buttons, change the window size and reposition the "Yes" and "No" buttons, another way is to create two windows in WPF. Once containing only "Yes" and "No" buttons and the another one with all the four buttons and launch the specific window as per the requirement.
I dont want to create any other window. Is there any way using which I can achieve this with only one window and skip the reositioning of controls, may be some panel or something, I am not sure.

Comment: you can use StackPanel control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a panel and when u need it make the panel visible, when u don't need it you make the panel invisible.`Visibilty.Collapsed`

You could also use a stackpanel [TUTORIAL](http://wpftutorial.net/StackPanel.html)

There are a lot of solutions to this question, just pick the right one suitable for your specific application.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`StackPanel`](http://wpftutorial.net/StackPanel.html) to layout the buttons. The visible buttons will be aligned correctly if the other buttons are hidden and collapsed.